# Flutter get coordinates from google maps

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I use the package `google_maps_flutter` to use Google maps in my app. My problem is how to set a listener, show when I press in the map to get the coordination of this place. I don't find anything in documentation.
The only thing which I find is with controllerMap, which I use to set marker listener, is that it has a method,
`.addListener(listener)`

Any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib

You should look through the examples.

The plugin is in alpha.
Here is the how to add on tap listener

Comment: I have seen it but I didn't find anything relevant. Can you be more specific? The only tap thing which I find and I use is the onMarkerTapped

Comment: If its not there then, it is probably not implemented
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/39ba555c4ccf640b2b31943d7befc9b5cba5781d/packages/google_maps_flutter/lib/src/controller.dart

GoogleMapController has very little features at the moment. The plugin is in alpha

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem using the onMarkerTapped callback methods below:

Note: mapController below is an instance of the GoogleMap Controller

```
 mapController.**onMarkerTapped**.add((marker){

      String title= marker.options.infoWindowText.title;
      String latitude= marker.options.position.latitude.toString();
      String longitude= marker.options.position.longitude.toString();

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

google map plugin has a lot of errors:), I prefer using this plugin : [flutter_map](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_map)

full example :

```
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';

class ContactPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ContactPageState createState() => new ContactPageState();
}

class ContactPageState extends State<ContactPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {


  static LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(51.5, -0.09);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      new LatLng(51.5, -0.09);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double heigh = screenSize.height;
    TextStyle whiteStyle = new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white);
    return new Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, left: 1.0, right: 1.0),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: new FlutterMap(
            options: new MapOptions(
                center: myLocation,
                zoom: 15.0,
                maxZoom: 15.0,
                minZoom: 3.0,
                onTap: _handleTap),
            layers: [
              new TileLayerOptions(
                  urlTemplate:
                      "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                  subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
              new MarkerLayerOptions(markers: markers)
            ],
          )
          )),
    );
  }
  _handleTap(LatLng point) {
    setState(() {
      myLocation = point;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is currently not available in version 2.0 of the google flutter plugin, however there are two pull requests that have added this functionality.

- [1121](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1121)
- [941](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/941)

Pull request 1121 has example code on how to use the tap functionality.

Answer (score 1):

With the current documentation, I only made the following change to the example of @lionelsanou and @Pradeep given above:

```
  String latitude= marker.values.first.position.toString();
  String longitude= marker.values.last.position.toString();
```

and it worked for me.